# How can I get rid of condensation on a fixed lens?

Tags: lens, condensation

I accidentally left my Nikon Coolpix L31 near some water and when I came back to take a picture of something the inside of the lens is all white and foggy when I turn it on. Can somebody help?

I tried cleaning it but its inside, and I don't want to take of the lens unless its the only way to clean it

tried leaving it out for a bit - it helped but its still a bit foggy

Answer (score 2):

If it does not clear -- place in sealed jar with rice. Better get some desiccant from the hardware store. If you can't find, then heat some charcoal in the oven. Place hot (not burning) in a sealed glass jar. When this cools, add the camera. Sounds crazy but heating charcoal activates it and it will act as a desiccant (drying agent).

Comment: The problem with rice is that it is awful dusty...

Answer (score 1):

Your lens is most likely foggy from condensed moisture. You can try putting it in a plastic bag with some material that absorbs the moisture. Silica gel packs, like those that are often packed with sensitive equipment, would be ideal for the job, but some dry rice may help, too.

Putting the camera in a warm and very dry place may work, too. I dried my phone's camera with a hair drier, but that may be dangerous (excessive heat and possibly dust can be introduced).

Leave it there overnight or longer, until the fog disappears.